# applet Djnlp.versionEnabled doc

Tags: java, applet

Can some body explain when an applet should use "Djnlp.versionEnable" property, i cannot found the official documentation for this property, if some body have a link to the original source i will appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html